# google app engine datastore statistics are not showing

Tags: google-app-engine

I have deployed an app on Google App Engine and it's working fine. All the data is getting displayed in DataSotre Viewer but DataStore Statistics Page is continuously showing No Statistics Found. It's already more than 2 days since I deployed my app so it rules out the possibility of that Statistics will be generated after 1 day of deploying your app.

Comment: Check out `Last updated: * day, HH:MM:SS ago` on statistics page.

Comment: On the page it says statistics are generated at least once a day.  I find my stats are often over 36 hours old, so in reality it's less frequent than that.  They also take a long time to show up for new apps.  They'll show up eventually.  It's not a particularly useful page, except to help you realize how big your indexes are.

Comment: It's not showing anything except "No statistics found." on statistics page. Do I need to enable anything or add something to my code to enable Datastore Statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes GAE 1-2 days before generating reports. So have patience.